# Scroll DataGridView Programatically inside a panel on Button Click

Tags: c#, scroll, datagridview, panel

I have a datagridview inside a panel and I have placed two buttons, one above the panel and one below the panel. I want to scroll the datagridview on the button clicks, how can I achieve that? I am doing a windows application.

Comment: A vertical scroll bar on the `DataGridView` wont work?

Comment: @JohnG         As per the requirement Ihave to make use of the buttons to scroll the datagridview.